# android:onClick = "functionName" did not recognize the function name in Fragment subclass

Tags: android, xml

`android:onClick = "clickFun1"` for `Button` in my layout xml file did not recognize the `clickFun1()` method mentioned in `DipToVol extends Fragment` class. Android Studio says that method nowhere used.

```
public class DipToVol extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    public double calVol(short rad, short len, int height) {
        double area;
        area = (Math.PI * Math.pow(rad, 2) / 2) - Math.pow(rad, 2) * Math.asin(1 - (height / (double)rad)) - (rad - height) * Math.sqrt(height * (2 * rad - height));
        return area*len*0.000001;
    }

    //here android studio says this method never used
    public void clickFun1 (View view)
    {
        int dipHSD = 0, dipMS = 0;
        final short radHSD = 1219;
        final short lenHSD = 6810;
        final short radMS = 999;
        final short lenMS = 6804;
        double volHSD, volMS;

        EditText dipH = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipHSD1);
        EditText dipM = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipMS1);

        TextView volH = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volHSD1);
        TextView volM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volMS1);
        try {
            dipHSD = Integer.parseInt(dipH.getText().toString());
            volHSD = calVol(radHSD, lenHSD, dipHSD);
            volHSD = Math.round(volHSD);
            volH.setText(volHSD + "");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            volH.setText("");
        }
        try{ dipMS = Integer.parseInt(dipM.getText().toString());
            volMS = calVol(radMS, lenMS, dipMS);
            volMS = Math.round(volMS);
            volM.setText(volMS + "");
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){volM.setText("");}

    }

    //here android studio says this method never used
    public void clearFun1(View view){
        EditText dipH = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipHSD1);
        EditText dipM = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipMS1);

        TextView volH = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volHSD1);
        TextView volM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volMS1);

        volH.setText("");
        volM.setText("");
        dipH.setText("");
        dipM.setText("");
   } 

}
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/section_label1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#4ab4b2">


       <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_weight ="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
           android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HSD Dip"
                android:id="@+id/lableDipHSD"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/dipHSD1"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MS Dip"
                android:id="@+id/lableDipMS"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:id="@+id/dipMS1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="HSD Volume"
                android:id="@+id/lableVolHSD"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/volHSD1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="MS Volume"
                android:id="@+id/lableVolMS"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/volMS1"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>




    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clearBtn"
        android:id="@+id/clearBtn1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clearFun1"
        android:background="#fa0690"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/calcBtn1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/calcBtn1"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calcBtn"
        android:id="@+id/calcBtn1"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickFun1"
        android:background="#fa0690"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clearBtn1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/contentView"
        android:alpha="0.8" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me where I am doing it wrong. When I run the code, App is crashing. Error log says the `clickFun1()` doesnt found.

//The logcat

```
09-10 13:49:24.823 2718-2718/com.example.siv.mahalaxmipetroleums E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method clickFun1(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'calcBtn'
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have changed the `mainActivity.java` as follows. Moving code from fragment subclass to `mainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.siv.mahalaxmipetroleums;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    Button clearBtn_f1,calcBtn_f1,clearBtn_f2,calcBtn_f2;



    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        clearBtn_f1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearBtn1);
        clearBtn_f2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearBtn2);
        calcBtn_f1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn1);
        calcBtn_f2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn2);

        clearBtn_f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearFun1(v);
            }
        });
        clearBtn_f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearFun2(v);
            }
        });

        calcBtn_f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickFun1(v);
            }
        });

        calcBtn_f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickFun2(v);
            }
        });


         }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
   public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
        // */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

      /*  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

           if (position == 0) {
                return new Fragment_One();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new Fragment_Two();
            } else
                return new Fragment_Three();//PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Dip-Vol";
                case 1:
                    return "Vol-Dip";
                case 2:
                    return "Temp-Dens";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void clickFun1 (View view)
    {
        short dipHSD = 0, dipMS = 0;
        final short radHSD = 1219;
        final short lenHSD = 6810;
        final short radMS = 999;
        final short lenMS = 6804;
        double volHSD, volMS;

        EditText dipH = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipHSD1);
        EditText dipM = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipMS1);

        TextView volH = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volHSD1);
        TextView volM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volMS1);
        try {
            dipHSD = Short.parseShort(dipH.getText().toString());
            Liquid_Volume dtvh = new Liquid_Volume(radHSD,lenHSD,dipHSD);
            volHSD = dtvh.getVolume();
            volHSD = Math.round(volHSD);
            volH.setText(volHSD + "");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            volH.setText("");
        }
        try{ dipMS = Short.parseShort(dipM.getText().toString());
            Liquid_Volume dtvm = new Liquid_Volume(radMS,lenMS,dipMS);
            volMS = dtvm.getVolume();
            volM.setText(volMS + "");
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){volM.setText("");}

    }

    public void clearFun1(View view){
        EditText dipH = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipHSD1);
        EditText dipM = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dipMS1);

        TextView volH = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volHSD1);
        TextView volM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volMS1);

        volH.setText("");
        volM.setText("");
        dipH.setText("");
        dipM.setText("");
    }

    public void clickFun2 (View view)
    {
        EditText volH = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.volHSD2);
        EditText volM = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.volMS2);

        TextView dipH = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dipHSD2);
        TextView dipM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dipMS2);

        double volHSD = 0, volMS = 0;
        final double radHSD = 121.9;
        final double lenHSD = 681.0;
        final double radMS = 99.9;
        final double lenMS = 680.4;
        double dipHSD, dipMS;

        try {
            volHSD = Double.parseDouble(volH.getText().toString());
            Liquid_Height HSD = new Liquid_Height(radHSD,lenHSD,volHSD);
            dipHSD = HSD.getDip();
            //String.format("%f",dipHSD);
            //dipH.setText(Double.toString(dipHSD));
            dipH.setText(dipHSD + "");
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            dipH.setText("");
        }
        try{ volMS = Double.parseDouble(volM.getText().toString());
            Liquid_Height MS = new Liquid_Height(radMS,lenMS,volMS);
            dipMS = MS.getDip();
            //String.format("%f",dipHSD);
            //dipM.setText(String.format("%f",dipMS));
            dipM.setText(dipMS + "");
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            dipM.setText("");
        }

    }

    public void clearFun2(View view){
        EditText volH = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.volHSD2);
        EditText volM = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.volMS2);

        TextView dipH = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dipHSD2);
        TextView dipM = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dipMS2);

        volH.setText("");
        volM.setText("");
        dipH.setText("");
        dipM.setText("");
    }

}
```

Then I have my fragment_one.java and rest other fragments in the same way.

```
public class Fragment_One extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    }

}
```

Here the app crashes immediately after i try to open it.

Logcat says the following

```
09-12 07:17:40.600 2283-2291/com.google.android.gms E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                  java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                      at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:190)
                                                                      at ...
```

Comment: What if you move your `clickFun1()` method in the Activity which contains the Fragment?

Comment: @Rotwang I did move the clickFun1() method into mainActivity.java leaving my DipToVol class only for onCreateView to inflate the fragment layout file. Still the app crashing when i click the buttons.

Comment: When you say `app crashing` you should at least post your logcat.

Comment: @Rotwang The same code worked well in the app without fragments and tabs. That was simple calculator. This time i used code of two such calculators into two fragments (two tabs /swipe views). The app is opening, all fragments layouts are fine, but the moment i click any of the buttons, it is crashing.

Comment: logcat please... `it is crashing` means nothing.

Comment: @Rotwang I added the logcat.

Comment: `Could not find method clickFun1(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute` tells you exactly what I suggested you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not an error. (The method warning, not the app crashing). The Java compiler doesn't know you've defined the listener in the XML, so since you never explicitly call those methods, it simply thinks that they are "never used"

Personally, I always setOnClickListener on my views from the Java code

Comment: When I run this, app is opening displaying the layout, but the moment i click any of those clickFun1 or clearFun1 , the app is crashing. Logcat says the clickFun1 function couldnot found at parent or ancestor so on..  When I used setOnClickListener on button inside the OnCreateView, the app crashing immediately after opening.

Comment: @SivaPrasad: "When I used setOnClickListener on button inside the OnCreateView, the app crashing immediately after opening" -- ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide *this code* and *this Java stack trace*.

Comment: @CommonsWare Last time i posted a similar question, android studio did not warn me that the method is never used. But today, when i edited some code and when found that did not work, then i came to initial code, this time AS warns about that.

Comment: @SivaPrasad CommonsWare has answered your previous question that you accepted as the answer, where he (as well as I) suggested to **remove** the XML click listener in favor of setting `OnClickListener` via Java

Comment: @SivaPrasad - maybe you tried the Java code and forgot to remove the XML setting? Maybe you were finding the button from the XML incorrectly in the Fragment when you tried to set the listener? Etc... It's hard to know what the problem is without seeing the reason the app crashed, but it's error message would certainly be different than your current one

Comment: @cricket_007 posted the changes i made to files and logcat. XML setting? android:onclick ? i deleted it before running the app. It will be very helpful for me (because i am new to programming and i wanted to create this calculator app  for our petrol filling station) , if you could try the code in your Android Studio and suggest me what changes actually i should do to make it work.

Comment: Okay... I don't see a SQLite usage in your code, but that error in completely unrelated to the button. What about `method 'close' not called` is not clear to you? I assume you have a Cursor object that is never closed?

Comment: @cricket_007  did not use any such cursor object any my java files. Logcat did not mention any file or code from the files i created.

Comment: Are you sure? You've cut off the logcat in your post and only put the exception and the first few lines.

Comment: I have cut off the logcat because the question was exceeding 30,000 words. But in that code, there were only at... type statements which did not mentioned any code from mine

Comment: If you reached the character limit, then create a [mcve] of the first problem. You do not need to show the entire Activity code with the PlaceholderFragment and SectionPagerAdapter and everything related to those.

Answer (score 1):

When Android is running and checking for onClick methods, it only looks in the main Activity class. You **cannot** put an onClick method in a fragment. Fragments are not the same as activities, so they should not be abused.

Another question has the same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429157/6754053

Comment: You do realize that the post you linked to was asked by the same user as this one, yes?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried what commonsware suggested. I first tried the first one using onClickListener. But the app crashing immediately. Next i tried the second suggestion, keeping onClick in xml layout. But it is happening the same way i quoted in my previous question i.e it is crashing when click any of the buttons. Then I tried moving all code to mainActivity.java and using onClickListeners on buttons. This time again crashing immediately even before displaying the layout.

Comment: @cricket_007 Then these are duplicate questions. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Removing this line from your layout's root might help;

```
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: That doesn't actually control anything other than what activity is controlled by the IDE editor. It's removed when the app is compiled

Answer (score 0):

As other users said. you cannot use `onClick` attribute with Fragments. But this universe has Jake Wharton and his awesome libraries including Butterknife. [Check this out.](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)